# How to convert elements of a string array into a string with elements in single quotes and comma seperated in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array like this

```
      arr=["japan","china","india"];
```

i want to convert it into a string like this

```
      str="'japan','china','india'"
```

join() wouldnt fullfill my requirement  as it gives result like below..

```
      str="japan,china,india"
```

Any help pls....

Comment: Have you tried searching for similar solutions? maybe formatting the string?

Answer (score 1):

Use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and continue adding to the accumulator.

```js
let res = arr.reduce((acc,curr,ind) => acc += (ind == arr.length -1) ? `'${curr}'` :`'${curr}',` ,'')
```

Comment: @ArjunChandrasekaran It returns the resulting string, you can store it in a variable. Like I have updated in the answer now

Answer (score 1):

When declaring variables always use `var` or `let`:

```
let arr = ["japan","china","india"];
let str = arr.map(x => "'" + x + "'").join(); // 'japan','china','india'
```

Comment: Nice, you just need to wrap the answer in double quotes.

Comment: @Spangle As written on MDN: _"String literals can be specified using single or double quotes, which are treated identically, or using the backtick character"_. [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

Answer (score 1):

Yop,

You can use something like this:

```js
['japan', 'china', 'india'].map(country => `'${country}'`).toString();
// output: 'japan','china','india'
```

The .map will quote each element of your array, then the .toString will join all the array elements (you can use .join instead if you want another seperator between your elements).

Comment: Close, you just need to wrap the result with double quotes :)

Comment: Are you sure? I understand from the question the double quotes are just because it's how he format his string, no?

Comment: Yeah, they wanted the string to be "'japan','china','india'"

Comment: Everyone seem to have understand without them though ^^'

Comment: Yeah, my bad sorry, gave you an up.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.reduce((acc,val, index) => {
if (index === 0 ) { 
acc = acc + `'${val}'`
} else {
acc = acc + `, '${val}'`
}
return acc;
},'');
```

Comment: @ArjunChandrasekaran the whole thing returns a string. Run it an find out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
            let arr = ["japan", "china", "india"];
            let str = '';
            for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (i < arr.length-1)
                    str += "\'" + arr[i] + "\'" + ",";
                else
                    str += "\'" + arr[i] + "\'";
            }
            console.log(str);
</script>
```